# shifting(<<,>>) operator doesnot work well in php

Tags: php

i am trying to do simple program using php logical operator, when i try to invert the binary value using ~ operator it giving some symbol, instead of actual inverted value also when i try to shift the bits using using <<,>> it doesn't give expected value,help me?
here is the simple coding

```
<?php
$n=10;
$bin=decbin($n);
echo $bin;
//for onces complement
$com_value=~$bin; //this statement prints some IIIIIIIIIIIIIIII symbol instead of inverted value
echo $com_value;
$shift_value=$bin<<1;
echo $shift_value; //this  printing 2020 as result for binary number of ten 1010
?>
```

help me to get correct value,i have to complete one assignment using that, thanks in advance

Comment: Just because you use binary shift operators doesn't mean you have to convert the orginal integer to a zero-and-ones string beforehand. Remove the first `decbin()` and only use it for prettyfying output.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: This question doesn't need downvotes just becuase the OP was mistaken about the return value of a standard function. Homework or not as beginners we've all gotten stumped by simple mistakes like this.

Answer (score 2):

`decbin` returns a `string`, i.e. a sequence of `0` and `1` characters, with the binary representation of `$n`. This is not correct as you want to execute `~` and `<<` on the *binary* value, which is simply `$n`. Although `$n` "looks decimal" in the source code, it is stored as 0's and 1's in your memory.

Try to remove that conversion into a string and use `$n` directly.

Comment: thanks sir but actually i need to do that operation in binary number, is any another way to convert the decimal value into binary number

Comment: $n is stored binary... See my answer again.